# Biztalk Getting root element Exception error

Tags: biztalk, soapui

I have developed the application in which i have taken Listener and 2 Request Operations One is for Checking prime number,and other is to find the prime numbers in a series.
Deployed the application ,and testing it with SOAP UI,first operation is working fine and giving the response.
But the second operation is giving below error.

```
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Root element is missing.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
               <Message>Root element is missing.</Message>
               <StackTrace>at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance.EndOperation(IAsyncResult result)
   at AsyncInvokeEndEndTwoWayMethod(Object , Object[] , IAsyncResult )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AsyncMethodInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object instance, Object[]&amp; outputs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
               <Type>System.Xml.XmlException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: You show the error, but not the code, how could we help?

Comment: Which code should i post I can upload the image of orchestration but that is not allowed for me.I have taken 2 send ports and one Request port with 2 operations. first operation just works fine but second operation is not working and giving above error.

Comment: A response message sent to adapter "WCF-BasicHttp" on receive port "WcfReceivePort_BiztalkPrimeNumber/BiztalkPrimeNumberService" with URI "/BiztalkPrimeNumber/BiztalkPrimeNumberService.svc" is suspended. 
 Error details: Root element is missing. 
 MessageId:  {873AB207-15D7-4C0C-B269-EBF5D4AEBC14}
 InstanceID: {E661EE45-A60E-47BF-B1D8-AC0CCE86D52A} Getting this error in Event Viewer

Comment: Your schema is not synced with your WSDL, try to update it, and also as said before with no code we can't tell you nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually has something to do with the message stream being read but the pointer not being reset.  Are you using any custom pipeline components?

Comment: Thanks I have solved that error, Actually wrong map was used in my Biztalk project, thats why such error was coming,but it took me whole day to resolve it.